# How to split a string array and then compare every first index of that splited array with a Character?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to take array of  string from the user and output just those string indexes which starts from the character "A". 
Is there a way to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
const int size=3;
void input(string name[size]);
void byname(string name[size]);
struct employee
{
    string name[size];  
}emp;
int main() 
{
    input(emp.name);
    byname(emp.name);
    return 0;
}
void input(string name[size]){
    cout<<"Enter Names of the employees:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    cin>>emp.name[i];
}

void byname(string name[size])
{
    int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
        if(name[i]=="A")
        cout<<"Name starting with A is "<<emp.name[i];
        else if(name[i]=="a")
        cout<<"Name starting with a is "<<emp.name[i];
       }
}
```

Comment: Yes there is such a way. What have you tried and where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried comparing the whole string with character "A", as the string does not just include a single character so it did not work. I am asked to first take 10 persons names in a string array and then output just those names which starts from "A".

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't post it though.

Comment: It is a whole program, what I am asking is just a little part of it, Okay I will show you just that function on which I am stuck.

Comment: I have provided my code, now you can see, It would be great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In c++, you can use array indexing to access individual characters of a string, more about c++ strings here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ , 
Coming to your question, In that **byname function** , change the comparisons to :

```
if(name[i][0]=='A')
    cout<<"Name starting with A is "<<emp.name[i];
else if(name[i][0]=='a')
    cout<<"Name starting with a is "<<emp.name[i];
```

Do let me know if there are any other problems you are facing! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much, It was a great help.

Comment: I have another question, what if I want to check that particular string with its last character instead of first?

Comment: By using the same logic, using array indexing to access individual characters of the string. To check the last character, you need to check the last index, which can be obtained by subtracting 1 from the total length of string, more specifically,  int lastIndex = name[I].length() - 1;  and doing the comparison as if( name[I][lastIndex] == 'A') . You should look at the string documentation provided on the link mentioned above.